# Symfony 2.3 - Validator.yml within my bundle not working

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I have 2 bundles, 1 works with the validation.yml file and one does not.

Both bundles are set up exactly the same, i have googled high and low and i cannot seem to understand why.

I have created a form type here:

```
<?php
namespace Brs\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class Usertype extends AbstractType
{
    protected $fname;
    protected $lname;
    protected $email;
    protected $mobile;
    protected $active;
    protected $mentor;
    protected $initialized;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('fname','text',array('label'=>'First Name'))
        ->add('lname','text',array('label'=>'Last Name'))
        ->add('email','email',array('label'=>'Email'))
        ->add('mobile','text',array('label'=>'Mobile'))
        ->add('active','choice',array(
            'label'=>'Active?',
            'choices'=>array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'expanded'=>true,
            'multiple'=>false
        ))
        ->add('mentor','choice',array(
            'label'=>'Mentor?',
            'choices'=>array('0'=>'No','1'=>'Yes'),
            'expanded'=>true,
            'multiple'=>false
        ))
        ->add('Add Player?','submit');
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'user';
}
```

public function setFname($fname)
    {
        $this->fname = $fname;

```
    return $this;
}

public function getFname()
{
    return $this->fname;
}

public function setLname($lname)
{
    $this->lname = $lname;

    return $this;
}

public function getLname()
{
    return $this->lname;
}

public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;

    return $this;
}

public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function setMobile($mobile)
{
    $this->mobile = $mobile;

    return $this;
}

public function getMobile()
{
    return $this->mobile;
}

public function setActive($active)
{
    $this->active = $active;

    return $this;
}

public function getActive()
{
    return $this->active;
}

public function setMentor($mentor)
{
    $this->mentor = $mentor;

    return $this;
}

public function getMentor()
{
    return $this->mentor;
}

public function setInitialized($initialized)
{
    $this->initialized = $initialized;

    return $this;
}

public function getInitialized()
{
    return $this->initialized;
}
```

}

This is my validation.yml in bundle/Resources/config:

```
Brs\UserBundle\Form\Type\UserType:
properties:
    fname:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 3
    lname:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 3
    email:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 3
```

This is my controller that builds the form from the class and renders it renders fine:

```
<?php
namespace Brs\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
// use Brs\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Brs\UserBundle\Form\Type\UserType;

class UserController extends Controller{
    public function indexAction(Request $request){
        $user = new UserType();


        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(),$user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if($form->isValid()){
            echo 'yes';
        }
        //print_r($user);

        return $this->render(
            'BrsUserBundle:User:userForm.html.twig',
            array(
                'title'=>"Add Player",
                'form'=>$form->createView()
            ));
    }
}
```

?>

In app/config/config.yml i have these params set for validation:

```
    validation:      { enabled: true, enable_annotations: false }
```

Now when I submit the form with no data the request hits the controller and the method

```
$form->isValid();
```

is called, this returns true.

This should return false as my constraints in my validation.yml file do not allow blank fields to be processed and should trigger the form to render the field errors within the template.

I am clearly missing something here, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not validate your UserType, but the User object itself. Also the second argument of createForm() needs to be a User object.

```
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType(),$user);
```

validation.yml:

```
Brs\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
       # constraint list
```